# How to convert 2D ArrayList to String?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, multidimensional-array, netbeans-6.9

I am trying to convert values of a 2D ArrayList to a string to that I can print them onto a JTextArea. However, everytime I run my program, the 2D ArrayList is still in the square brackets. Does anyone know a fix for this?

```
private void listButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    for (int row = 0; row <= count; row++) {

        employeeDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(employeeRecords.get(row)));

    }
}
```

Comment: When you say 2D ArrayList, do you have ArrayList< ArrayList<String>>? What does employeeRecords.get(row) return?

Comment: @Makketronix  Yeah I have that setup, and the employeeRecords.get(row) is supposed to print each row of the 2D ArrayList into the JTextArea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your for loop :

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String value : employeeRecords.get(row)) {
    builder.append(value);
}
String text = builder.toString();
employeeDisplay.setText(text);
```

OR

```
String formatedString = employeeRecords.get(row).toString()
    .replace(",", "")  //remove the commas
    .replace("[", "")  //remove the right bracket
    .replace("]", "")  //remove the left bracket
    .trim();  
employeeDisplay.setText(formatedString);
```

Comment: The top one works for me, but is there any way to make a break to a new line after each row of the 2D array is printed? As of right now it is just printing all elements on the one line.

Comment: Add   builder.append("\n"); after builder.append(value);                                 hope it helps. Also, could you please accept the answer or upvote it. It helps other people to know that an answer has been found

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), you could use `Collectors#joining`

```
employeeDisplay.setText(employeeRecords.get(row)
                                       .stream()
                                       .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```